# HtmlAgilityPack DocumentNode.ChildNodes returns empty nodes

Tags: c#, web-crawler, html-agility-pack

I built a website crawler for a [price comparison site](https://www.idealo.de) in Java and would like to reimplement it in C#. I used Jsoup in Java and HtmlAgilityPack (HAP) is a good counterpart for .NET. After crawling an example product of this [site](https://www.idealo.de/preisvergleich/OffersOfProduct/5473234_-galaxy-s8-midnight-black-samsung.html), I noticed that HAP returns empty html nodes. They aren't part of the original html when I view-source that site. The node only contains formatting signs like `"\n\t\t\t\t"`. Jsoup doesn't show this behaviour, so I'm curious what HAP is doing there. A tiny code example how I retrieve my node:

```
using Fizzler.Systems.HtmlAgilityPack; // Without that I can't retrieve nodes 
                                      // by searching for a certain class
[...]
var client = new WebClient()
{
    Encoding = Encoding.UTF8
};
var doc = new HtmlDocument();
var html = client.DownloadString("https://www.idealo.de/preisvergleich/OffersOfProduct/5473234);
doc.LoadHtml(html);
var root = doc.DocumentNode;
var data = root.QuerySelector(".pageContent-wrapper").FirstChild;
```

This code returns an empty node with `"\n\t\t\t\t"` as content, whereas it should return a script node with javascript content.

Critical html part:

```
<main class="pageContent-wrapper">
<!-- Here is nothing!-->
            <script type="application/ld+json">{...json...}</script>
```

Why isn't `<script>` the direct child, but some empty node?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you want to get this json

```
var json = root.SelectSingleNode("//*[@class='pageContent-wrapper']/script").InnerText;
var jobj = JObject.Parse(json);
```

Comment: NonetheIess I don't understand why HAP adds an empty node between the <main> and <script> part... the <script> should be the `FirstChild` not the second one.

Comment: The <script> is available as FirstChild with my code?

Comment: If it is a question, I don't understand what you are asking. BTW: Why don't you try above code before continueing

Comment: in my code above the <main> node is available as variable `data`... so logically the `FirstChild` of the <main> node should be the <script> node... but it isn't. The FirstChild is a empty node marked as `#text` with content `"\n\t\t\t\t"`. BTW: I know that that works because you access the script component directly with the query... also I tested out 30s ago

Comment: So, `#text` is the first node containing those empty chars, not script. What is your question?

Comment: Yes, that's right. Why isn't it the <script> is my question.

Comment: Because there are some blank chars between main & script. And HAP returns them as *#text*. I don't get why it surprises you (it is not `<main ....><script>` and  it is completely OK to have some text betwwen them which may be displayed on page)

Comment: Because I wouldn't regard it as a html node. It's rather some file formatting think, but I thought that `FirstChild` returns the first html node and not the first anything.

Comment: `html != xml` similar but not equal.

Comment: hmm interesting... but why does Jsoup disregard such text blocks. Fail-by-design or was this done on purpose?

Comment: Sorry I've never used Jsoup and am not interested why it does so.